# JavaScript single responsibility and callbacks

Tags: javascript

Yesterday I was reviewing some Java code with a co-worker and we were discussing the Single Responsibility Principle. We refactored the code a bit and it complies very well to this principle.

Since I'm more of a front-end guy instead of backend I'm mostly writing JavaScript. Because of the SRP discussion I was looking at my code and found the following:

```
retrieveLabels : function() {
    getResultFromService(this, url, function(labelObject) {
        this.setLabels(labelObject)
    });
}
```

This function, to me, doesn't comply to SRP, it retrieves the labels (asynchroniously) and it stores this object in a variable. So basicly I want to return `labelObject` and pass the object to another function.

The problem here for me is the callback because it is asynchroniousl, how would one make this SRP compliant?

Comment: so you want to synchronously return the asynchronously retrieved `labelObject`?

Comment: This function has no problem with SRP; its responsibility is clearly defined and minimal. It's debatable whether the function name clearly describes what exactly it's doing, but that's about it.

Comment: `it retrieves the labels` -- no it doesn't. The function `getResultFromService` retrieves the labels. This function ONLY pass the return labels to `this.setLabels()`

Comment: Note that if this was synchronous the code would be `this.setLabels(getResultFromService(url))` -- nobody would accuse the function of retrieving the label

Comment: You can modify it to take a callback as parameter, like this.
`this.retrieveLabels(this.setLabels);`. Or you can use Promises instead of callbacks